# Filter Wagtail's search results using a ParentalManyToManyField

Tags: wagtail

I am building a search engine based on Wagtail, and after going through the documentation many times, I still encounter an issue. 
I am using v1.9 **categories** feature, and Elastic Search v5 backend.

Here is my PublicationPage model (the one I want results from), and the DisciplineCategory model (the one I want to filter from).

```
# models.py 

class PublicationPage(AbstractForm): 
    disciplines = ParentalManyToManyField('home.DisciplineCategory', blank=True)
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.RelatedFields('disciplines', [
            index.FilterField('name')
        ])
    ]

class DisciplineCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Discipline'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Disciplines'
```

When I run

`./manage.py update_index`

I get

`ValueError: 'disciplines' does not resolve to an item that supports prefetching - this is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related().`

As it strongly relies on django-modelcluster, I am quite lost about were to start looking for a solution...
The only index.FilterFieldexample I found is this one in the test of wagtail repo: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c6666c6de5e83bf94d18324858c121e6584ba47d/wagtail/tests/search/models.py#L19
But it's based on TaggableManager, so, don't really know if it applies here.

Hope someone will be able to help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever have any luck getting a `ParentalManyToManyField` to work with `prefetch_related` by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, I am not working anymore with Wagtail/Django, it is a bit far away behind me, and I did not recall if I solve this issue :/